# Why does this create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

This was one of my algorithm questions at FreeCodeCamp.com :

---

### Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.

If I don't put a break in my "if statement", I get a "potential infinite loop" warning. Why is that? I thought if the condition was false, the for loop would continue on to the next iteration.

//my solution

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {
    //This is the code in question
       arr.splice(i, 0, num);
       break;
    }
    else {
      arr.push(num);
    }
  }
  return arr.indexOf(num);
}
```

Comment: Because you're removing something from the array then adding something to it. In the other case, you're adding to the array. So the array will just keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is never going to be false once you've inserted the number into the array, because `arr[i]` is always going to be the same element that got you into the if block in the first place - it's just been moved up one index.

```
var arr = [500];
var num = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {                // arr[0] = 500, so we enter the block

       arr.splice(i, 0, num);          // now the array is [100, 500], and the 
    }                                  // for loop is going to move onto arr[1]
                                       // which is still 500... so we'll enter the
                                       // if block again and insert another 100, etc etc.
```